# Xamarin forms IOS socket dosn't connect after restart

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, xamarin.forms

**My Situation.**

Im Building a Xamarin Forms V5.0.0.2291 App. When i deploy this app on my physical device, the following code opens a TCP connection to my PC

```
   do
    {
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket(EndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    result = socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint, null, null);
                    success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10000, true);

                    if (!socket.Connected)
                    {
                        socket.Dispose();
                        ConnectionLost?.Invoke(this, null);
                    }
                
            }
            catch { }
        } while (!socket.Connected);
```

After i Restart the device and open the App again, it displays a permission popup with "your App" wants to find deviceses in you local network etc....

the code above is wrapped in a while loop and only exits when its truely connected.
I confirm this popup but nothing happends anymore. it cannot establich a connection.

On the IOS Simulator it works without problems but on the physical device it does.
In the Privacy settings my app has the permission granted.

I've already googled a lot but I just can't find anything and I'm slowly running out of ideas..

**The concrete Question is:**

What do i need do too, to establish a connection even though this code works on Android and IOS simulator perfectly?

Comment: first, you have an empty `catch` block so if anything does go wrong you'll never know.  Second - I am not a socket expert - but calling `BeginAsync` in a while loop without any callback handler seems like a bad idea

Comment: At minimum, add debug print statements, so you can find out what is happening. Obviously the first print to add is inside `catch`. But you also want to know what lines of code were reached. AND if something goes wrong, does it make it to a second attempt in the loop? I think not - I don't understand why your debugger connected to physical device didn't catch an exception on the final line - you do `while (!socket.Connected);`, but you already called `socket.Dispose();`, so that is an invalid test to make (if anything went wrong the first time).

Comment: After Dispose, do `socket = null;`. Then loop can be `while (socket == null);` (In your final release, don't let it loop forever; if it fails 3 times in a row, its probably never going to work, so you should pop up message to user. With a button that lets them try again if they want to.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i simplified the code a bid to make it more visual appealing but it gives  no exception at this point. I changed it like you adviced and mate a few other changes and now it kinda works :/